# Default route for a restful web service to return a Json object

Tags: rest, spark-java

I am using spark-java framework. I have a route: /users. But when i enter: /users/:id it returns 404. But I want to return a Json object saying :

```
{
  "default_url": "localhost:4567/users"
}
```

This is my /users route.

```
Spark.get("/users", "application/json", (request, response) -> {
            response.status(200);
            response.type("application/json");
            return (new UserDaoImpl().getAllUsers());
        }, new JsonTransformer());
```

I get an error like below and then a 404 on the front end

```
[qtp2868117-22] INFO spark.webserver.MatcherFilter - The requested route [/users/1] has not been mapped in Spark
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a placeholder to your route.

```
Spark.get("/users/:id", "application/json", (request, response) -> {
    response.status(200);
    response.type("application/json");
    return (new UserDaoImpl(request.params(":id")).getAllUsers());
}, new JsonTransformer());
```

See docs http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#routes

Answer (score 1):

Add another rule, which matches that case:

```
Spark.get("/users/:id", (request, response) -> {
    response.status(200);
    response.type("application/json");
    return "{\"default_url\": \"localhost:4567/users\"}";
});
```